# Android relative layout problem

Tags: java, android

I just can't display the button at the bottom of the screen. I have 2 textviews and 2 edittexts set as gone, and they become visible when user clicks checkbox. It's only then that my button gets positioned properly Otherwise it  sits on top of the app at launch of my app.(see here: http://www.shrani.si/f/3V/10G/4nnH4DtV/layoutproblem.png)
 I also tried android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" but that doesnt help either.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


 <TextView android:id="@+id/txt1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Krajevna skupnost: "
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

 <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/ks_prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt1"    
/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/txt2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Zadeva: "
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner1" />

 <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/pod_prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt2"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Zadeva: "
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner2" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/prvi" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/tv1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/prvi"
    android:text="Vsebina: " />
<EditText android:id="@+id/drugi" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/tv2" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cek" android:text="Obveščaj o odgovoru"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/drugi" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv3" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/cek"
    android:text="Email: " 
    android:visibility="gone"/> 
<EditText android:id="@+id/tretji" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/tv3"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv4" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/tretji"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Telefon: " /> 

<EditText android:id="@+id/cetrti" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv4" />


    <Button android:id="@+id/gumb"
    android:text="Klikni"
    android:typeface="serif" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_below="@id/cetrti" />

           </RelativeLayout>

          </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it o 2.1 device - and it looked ok as it is . Button is positioned below checkbox. So i'm not sure what the problem is.
As a quick fix that gonna work for sure - change relative layout to the LinearLayout. It little bit more expensive, but for your purpose IMO should work

Comment: I think he wants to get the button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: question is does he want to have this button  be scrolled with the content or not. By his layout design, he intended whole layout to be scrolled including the button.

Comment: I tried my code on 1.6 emulator and it worked fine. Problem is on 1.5. Then i changed my layout to Linear(inside scrollview) and now everything is good. 
Thank you guys for your swift response.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ScrollView and set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your bottom button. Also remove this line: android:layout_below="@id/cetrti".
If you really need the ScrollView, you could make it something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
       ...
       <RelativeLayout
          ...
       </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   <Button
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in a RelativeLayout doesn't work with a child set to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` (well it works, but it appears to basically set the height to fill_parent.)

See RelativeLayout docs where it explicitly mentions this as not supported:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html